# Best practice to create a user in table and invite them to login

Tags: laravel, architecture

I am working on a Laravel project.  I need to be able to create a user, mark that user with a number for their 'plan_id', and then invite them to log in and change their password.  Currently, I am creating a user, adding the 'plan_id', and setting the password to a generic term like 'password'.  I don't have info like their SSN or DOB that I could set it to initially.

While this does work, I don't know that it follows best practices.  The only other thing I can think of is setting up another table that matches up the user's email address to the 'plan_id'.  I don't want to do this because it makes it possible that the user accidentally signs up with another email and can't figure out why their portal is not working.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like a great idea to set all new passwords to "password". It looks like your application is creating users, then letting each user know they have an account, as opposed to the user initiating this process. This would mean that you can't have the user pick a password.

Consider not creating a password at all, but sending an email to each new user containing a link to your system with a unique key that you store in the database user record. The user could then access the system, and it would ask them to pick an email and password to be registered with. You could have the keys expire after a number of days.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to generate a completely random password for the user and then email them a password reset link. The potential pitfall of this is that password reset links expire, by default after 1 hour though you can change it in config/auth.php.